# Cocoa login sheet prevents the user from quitting the application

Tags: cocoa, view

In my OSX Application I am using a sheet to allow the user to log in. If the user first starts the application the sheet is displayed and the user has to enter his information.

Now as long as the sheet is open the user is not able to quit the application (unless he's force-quitting it).

Since the login is vital i don't want to provide a cancel button.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the `NSWindow`’s `preventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal` property accordingly:

```
- (void)windowDidLoad {
    [[self window] setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO];
}
```

Comment: Hmm this seems to be the property I need. However, I have an outlet to the window called 'mainWindow' but when I set the property like this it still prevents the user from quitting the application:

`    [self.mainWindow setPreventsApplicationTerminationWhenModal:NO];`

What am I missing?

Comment: _When_ do you change this property? You should do so from `-awakeFromNib`, `-windowDidLoad` or at the end of `-loadView` (depending on your setup) so `self.mainWindow != nil`. Also, changes to this property _might_ be ignored if the windows is already visible (I’m not sure).

Comment: It worked now. The problem was that I set the property on the underlying window, rather than on the sheet-window which is the modal window and therefore needs of course this property.

Thanks a lot!